# LWC Creating New Record

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a button in an object which is launching a LWC to bring up a pop-up window to allow the user to fill out fields and upon saving it will run Apex to not only create the new record, but also update other records accordingly.

I am attempting to add a new field to appear in the pop-up window. I've added the field to the object and it is added to the Page Layout. But the field is still not appearing in the pop-up "wizard".

Looking into the component, the cmp contains this :

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasSObjectName,lightning:actionOverride" access="global" >

    <ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.ModalSize}" />
    <c:programCommunicationWizard recordID='{!v.recordId}' sObjectName = '{!v.sObjectName}'></c:programCommunicationWizard>

</aura:component>
```

Are the fields being named in the LWC "programCommunicationWizard" ? I wouldn't think they are, but if so I don't know how to edit that.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: But this is a custom aura component name -programCommunicationWizard. You can open source code if it and check what happens inside

Comment: Unlike other code in Salesforce, you can't introspect or update LWC code in the Dev Console.  If you aren't already using VS Code, this would probably be a good time to check it out.  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.install_setup_develop

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. I looked into the LWC using VS Code and I can see the fields to appear are defined in a programCommunicationWizard.html file. Is it possible for me to just add the field to the html file, and then deploy just that file ? I've never deployed specifics with a LWC before I intend to look into it.